# How to export a 3D tube model without any error?

Tags: graphics3d, export, 3d-printing

I want to export a 3d tube model but I get two errors. I found that I won't get any error if I use a different model. So, how can I solve this problem in a simple way? Thanks.

```
model = 
    Graphics3D[
       Tube[                                
          BSplineCurve[
             {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
          ], 
          {5, 0}
       ]  
    ];

Export["MyTube.obj", model]
```

> Export::type: Graphics3D cannot be exported to the OBJ format.
>
> Export::type: RuleDelayed cannot be exported to the OBJ format.

[image][image]

Comment: I'm not sure *Mathematica* supports *OBJ*.  Can you export it in other formats, such as STL?

Comment: No,I can't export it in STL. But I get only one error this time, without the second error above.

Comment: Why do you want to export into .obj?  Will .eps or other format suffice?

Comment: I need it to do 3D printing. But I don't know why it can't be exported in 3D format, that's so weird. Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: @qgX, you definitely have problem with a definition of your figure. Something inside it contains `RuleDelayed` statement and it does not work during export to  "*.obj". I've the same problem with your code. It looks like a bug of exporting function..

Comment: Try `$ExportFormats` to find another format that will work with your printer.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have tried almost all the formats, it doesn't work yet.

Comment: @Rom38 Thanks a lot, but how can we solve this problem? I have no idea with it.

Comment: Something that may be related: `DiscretizeGraphics@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}, {1, 2}]` gives `EmptyRegion[3]`, which is apparently incorrect. Seems that the function for discretization can't handle `Tube` with a `List` as 2nd argument properly. Looks like a bug to me. You'd better report this to WRI.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much. I found that  `Export` can't handle Tube with a  `BSplineCurve` as 1st argument and  List as 2nd argument properly. I'm not good at English, so can you help me reporting? I just want to find a easy way to solve this problem,thanks again!

Comment: You can report in Chinese, they have Chinese employees. Sadly I can't think out a workaround at the moment. `ParametricPlot3D` may help, but it's not immediately clear to me how to reproduce the ends of the tube.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for editing my question! I found another problem with exporting models. I hope you can take a look when you are not busy. I am sincerely grateful to you!

Answer (score 1):

After some attempts, I found that problem is in `BSplineCurve`. The 3D-graphycs with `Tube` can be exported to "*.obj" without any problems. Therefore, all what you need is just an explicit definition of the point array inside the `Tube`.

```
bf = BSplineFunction[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, SplineClosed->True];
bfl = bf /@ Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}];
model = Graphics3D[Tube[bfl, {5, 0}]]
```

[image]

Now export to OBJ works well.

```
Export["MyTube.obj", model]
```

The step inside the `Table` after `bf` defines the detalization level for an image. Or you can set any amount of an arbitrary numbers between 0 and 1 to define your own surface quality.

Comment: Well, but this result is different from that of OP, isn't it?

Comment: @xzczd, The difference is in choice of the points of BSpline used for drawing. I don't know the point selection algorithm used by defaults in MMA , but changing the list of points in the second string of my answer one can change the result (including to have the same as in OP).

Comment: Can you add a result that's similar enough to that of OP?